# Popularity of Unix & Linux?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I ask here or on Super User?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/do-i-ask-here-or-on-super-user)

I was today stunned by the popularity of [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions), or rather the lack of it, compared to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions), [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions) and [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions). I am not trying to raise ire or controversy but it is concerning regarding the health of the community and does raise the question of why to ask here rather than one of the more popular overlapping sites.

AskUbuntu is a special case in that it is very newbie and GUI oriented and if I am looking for a more technical or CLI answer I come here even if I am running Ubuntu. I have not explored ServerFault or SuperUser as much.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu, just so you know, isn't tailored to any one audience except Ubuntu users.